# Stackoverflow Exception in MediatR Ping Sample?

Tags: c#, .net, mediatr, .net-7.0

Followed [official doc](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki):

While invoking the handler I get

> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Content root path: C:\S\Abhi.MediatR.SampleUsingControllers **Stack overflow**.
> **Repeat 260 times**:

> Could you help me with, what did is missing?

To invoke the handler, I had created a controller as below:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PingController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public PingController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Produces(typeof(string))]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = mediator.Send(new Ping());
            return Ok(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Oops something went wrong, {ex}");
        }
    }
}
```

Created Ping Request

```
public class Ping : IRequest<string>
{
}
```

Created PingHandler:

```
public class PingHandler : IRequestHandler<Ping, string>
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public PingHandler(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public async Task<string> Handle(Ping request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //return Task.FromResult("Pong");

        var response = await mediator.Send(new Ping());

        return response;
    }
}
```

In Program.cs have added the MediatR

> builder.Services.AddMediatR(typeof(Program));

As per doc I also tried adding as below:

> builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

Comment: why have you commented line `return Task.FromResult("Pong");` and calling `var response = await mediator.Send(new Ping());`?

Comment: You are recursively calling your handler, `mediator.Send(new Ping());` calls your handler, and then inside your handler you ask mediator to call the handler again, and again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception shows that you have an infinite recursion in your code. `Handle` method is again calling the `Ping` request again.

you need to uncomment the line `return Task.FromResult("Pong");`

and comment the below code.

```
var response = await mediator.Send(new Ping());
return response;
```